# Parsing JSON in apex - getting error System.StringException: Unrecognized base64 character: {

Tags: apex, files, base64

I am trying to parse a json i get from external system to salesforce using wrapper class.
The class works fine but for test class i am trying to hard code a string to test the class.

Below is the code, I have simplified the json for easier understanding.

```
String yourFilesContent = '{"MessageHeader":{"Version":"2.0"}}';
String base64Content = ( String ) JSON.deserialize( yourFilesContent, String.class );
Blob body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Content);
```

External system writes to file and i read from it and create data in salesforce objects.

When i run this code in developer console i keep getting the error as shown below

> Line: 5, Column: 1 System.StringException: Unrecognized base64
> character: {

How do i resolve this issue? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm really confused on this question. You have a string which is json object, you trying to deserialize as Json string, and then trying to base64 decode. Can you pl clarify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your simplification of the JSON here is detrimental, and is obscuring the issue. For purposes of providing an answer, I'll assume that there is some Base64 encoded string *somewhere* inside of the JSON you're actually receiving.

The primary issue I see is that you're trying to deserialize a JSON string into another `String`. This makes little sense. Your JSON here is not a single string, it's an *object*.

`String base64Content = ( String ) JSON.deserialize( yourFilesContent, String.class );` looks very wrong to me. When I try to run this as anonymous apex, I get that the result is simply the first character in the JSON string, the `{`. As that's not used as a symbol in the Base64 character set, it's no wonder you're getting an error.

You should be deserializing to a custom Apex class that you've created (which mimics the structure of the JSON), or deserializing untyped into a `Map<String, Object>`. At the end of the day, you need to deserialize first, then pull out the Base64 encoded component, *then* decode it.

e.g.

```java
String myJSON = '{"MessageHeader":{"Version":"2.0"}, "Content":{"B64Data":"IamBasE64="}}';

Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(myJSON);

Map<String, Object> content = (Map<String, Object>)result.get('Content');
String b64 = (String)content.get('B64Data');

System.debug(EncodingUtil.Base64Decode(b64));
```

Comment: Kudos to you to trying to understand that question in a reasonably correct way :) It was confusing for me to the point that my head hurts.

Comment: @derekf - Thank you in the name of simplification i think i deleted some critical elements. It also tells me that i have not understood the JSON part correctly.